# Randomized experiments in R

Tags: r, statistics

Here is a simple randomized experiment.

In the following code I calculate the p-value under the null hypothesis that two different fertilizers applied to tomato plants have no effect in plants yields.
The first random sample (x) comes from plants where a standard fertilizer has been used, while an "improved" one has been used in the plants where the second sample (y) comes from.

```
x <- c(11.4,25.3,29.9,16.5,21.1)
y <- c(23.7,26.6,28.5,14.2,17.9,24.3)
total <- c(x,y)
first <- combn(total,length(x))
second <- apply(first,2,function(z) total[is.na(pmatch(total,z))])
dif.treat <- apply(second,2,mean) - apply(first,2,mean)
# the first element of dif.treat is the one that I'm interested in 
(p.value <- length(dif.treat[dif.treat >= dif.treat[1]]) / length(dif.treat))
```

Do you know of any R function that performs tests like this one?

EDIT

```
# this is the equivalent independent t.test
t.test(x,y,alternative = "less",var.equal = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(perm)
permTS(x,y,alternative = "less")

data:  x and y
p-value = 0.3333
alternative hypothesis: true mean x - mean y is less than 0
sample estimates:
mean x - mean y 
      -1.693333
```

Answer (score 4):

The `boot` library is convenient for bootstrap and permutation tests, but it will not perform exact tests (which is OK most of the time). The `coin` library implements exact randomization tests as well.

Comment: Thank you! I just found some `permtest` in {BHH2}. It seems to work in a very similar way. By coincidence the same tomato dataset is used as an example!!!

Comment: Deducer also does monte carlo permutation tests: perm.t.test(x,y,"mean","less")